# Internet Explorer $.ajax / MVC JSON call failing

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, ajax, json

I have a relatively simple example of an MVC page that is using jQuery to make a POST to get some JSON data and then just show a success/failure message when it is done. The code works perfectly fine in the other browsers but in IE7/8 it seems to fail 4/5 times.

Here is the MVC View Page:

```
<asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <p id="message"></p>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent">
   <script type="text/javascript" src="<%= Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.min.js") %>"></script>

   <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url: "<%= Url.Action("GetData") %>",
            data: "{}",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data){
                $("#message").html("success");
            },
            error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown){
                $("#message").html("error: " + textStatus + "<br/>exception:" + errorThrown);
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
</asp:Content>
```

The controller is pretty simple as well:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetData()
{
    IList<string> people = new List<string>
    {
        "A",
        "B",
        "C",
        "D",
        "E"
    };

    return Json(people);
}
```

It seems to fail in IE 4 out of every 5 times roughly. I put some logging code in the controller and it calls the controller action every time, even when it fails. Does anyone see anything that I am doing wrong here?

When it hits my error handler function the textStatus is just set to "error" and errorThrown is undefined.

Comment: try with `{}` (or `null`) instead of `"{}"` as the data. Not sure if this is the problem, but sending `"{}"` I don't believe is going to translate to a valid key/value pair. Edit: Just realised your sending JSON to the action, but unless you have a JSON binder set up, this might be the problem

Comment: That worked! If you want to submit it as an answer I'll mark it as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `{}` (or `null`) instead of `"{}"` as the data.

As you're sending JSON to the action (`contentType` is set to JSON),  unless you have a JSON Value Provider Factory set up, this might be the cause of the problem.

Take a look at Phil Haack's article on **[Sending JSON to an ASP.NET MVC Action Method Argument](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/04/15/sending-json-to-an-asp-net-mvc-action-method-argument.aspx)** if this is something you're keen to do.